# front page keeps getting hacked

Tags: php, website, hacking

A similar attack keeps happenning on two of my sites (one is running latest Joomla, one is not).

It usually says "hacked by general" or something similar. When I check the files on one of them, there's a php file with similar code:

```
eval("?>".gzuncompress(base64_decode("eJzUvWmT4kiyKPp9... etc.
```

I also found a weird htm file that has a lot of messy code. If you need I can post these files zipped somewhere.

The attacks are always just an altered index page and this weird php file (but this time there was also another php page with this code:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['randomId'] != "Wo9QPY5euhw0bEKfNve82PW926VyluUh2HA3FGAidHDwA7h3wwZCOA2F2kva028q") {
    echo "Access Denied";
    exit();
}

// display the HTML code:
echo stripslashes($_POST['wproPreviewHTML']);

?>
```

I have restored the original index page but this is getting really annoying. I am also checking my pc for trojans as I've read that someone might have stolen my ftp credentials with a trojan (but for this one site I didn't even use ftp).

Help!

Comment: have you gotten rid of all the foreign files when you clean up the hack?

Comment: Unsecure upload ability somewhere on your server, or stolen FTP credentials~~~

Comment: So, what's your question? BTW, your side doesn't get hacked. It gets **cracked**.

Comment: I've had my homepage replaced by a Joomla exploiter before, that hole was patched in one of the 1.5.x versions, though.  Could be a newly discovered exploit.

Comment: @Winston Yes, every time I go through the files and delete the malware.

Comment: @Shad - probably FTP then as I don't have an upload ability anywhere on the site.

Comment: @Andy I think it's something else as the other site is not even running Joomla. Something more basic like FTP or something.

Answer (score 3):

Is all of the software installed on your server up to date (i.e. Joomla, any other applications you have installed)?

Have you changed your password for the hosting account and checked that no additional accounts have been created (in your control panel, if you have one).

After cleaning up from the hack, are you sure you removed ALL modifications: new files uploaded by the attacker, files modified by the attacker? This may well extend beyond just the index page to your site.

Comment: Yes, for one site I updated everything in Joomla and got rid of old unnecessary modules.. so far so good. BUT. The other site is not even running joomla, it's currently just an index page with a couple of images, css, a jquery file and a png transparency fix.

Comment: Username and password were changed before that, it got hacked. I'll change them again, but I have a feeling they're not coming in through there. As for the third question I uploaded a version of the front page from my hard drive, so AFAIK there are no mods.

Comment: What sort of hosting setup do you have? Are you responsible for the server maintenance (e.g. unmanaged dedicated server or VPS) or do you have a webhost (shared hosting, reseller account etc)? Are your two websites on separate hosting accounts?

Comment: @ara: hacks don't go into one site only, generally. they'll try to infect every page on every site hosted by the server.

Comment: I have a webhost (shared hosting with a couple of people I know as admins), both sites are on the same account.

Comment: It is also possible that your site has been compromised in an alternate way: a virus scan on every PC you use to edit these sites would be very wise, as would be changing your password for any services which stored the passwords for the compromised websites (email accounts, for example).

Comment: As both sites were on the same hosting account the second site could still have been compromised through Joomla. I would be tempted to speak to the people who are providing your hosting for two reasons: firstly, their server could have been compromised (either causing this problem, or as a result of it), and secondly so they can help you track down the method the attackers are using to enter your site.

Comment: @Dan Good idea, I'll send the web hosting people a mail and see where it goes from there

Answer (score 3):

Have you changed your password to something more secure?

Comment: It was pretty secure to begin with, uppercase and lowercase letters as well as numbers.

Comment: Have you changed your passwds? Change them now if the answer is no. Switch to ssh/sftp if that is an option for you.

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice!

Comment: @egorgy Ok, will do. I tried logging into my server with sftp but it wouldn't connect. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

First of, check your file permissions.  If this is happening often try running a 755 on all your files in the web_root. (except the folder(s) that need write permissions for file uploads).

Next, look at your logs very closely.  Is the app that isn't joomla homegrown?  I would look for abnormal URL requests.  Make sure that your logs are being logged elsewhere.  The hacker could be deleting the logs.

Do you know if root has been compromised?  Change root's password as well.

Do you use a cpanel editor for editing your files?  That is what most likely is the cause of the $_GET['randomID'] segment.  (http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=123442)

Posting that HTML file could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, yes that must be it with the $_GET segment. Where do I post a html file? Would pastebin take this kind of a file?

Comment: All file permissions are 644 for files, 755 for directories.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's going on on your site: http://blog.unmaskparasites.com/2011/05/05/thousands-of-hacked-sites-seriously-poison-google-image-search-results/

Thousands of websites have been hacked in this way.